# Header color is now pink

Tags: magento2, header

How do I fix my header background color. I cleared my cache and now it's pink. How do I fix this. I'm not very familiar with this software BTW..[enter link description here](https://midwestmegasquirt.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly Login to your Magento admin panel,
then go to Content->Design->Configuration
and then find your current applied theme and click on Edit
Like,https://i.imgur.com/ExioiJq.png

And then go to Html Head section and then add below code in Scripts and Style Sheets Field for removing pink color from your header and if you want to change pink color then you have to give particular color instead of unset.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NbFm.png

```
<style>
.page-header.type2.header-newskin .header.content {
    background: unset !important;
}
</style>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the class "**.page-header.type2.header-newskin .header.content**"
in your theme, after you find this class in .css or .less file change the background color you want.

after that Run command in command prompt

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
phpbin/magento cache:flush;
phpbin/magento cache:clean;
```

it will work

Let me know if any Query,

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using [Porto](https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/) (third-party) theme for your Storefront. It provides wide range of design options within Magento admin panel.

I think you accidently updated one of the options from Store > Configuration. That's why background color of header in your storefront changed to pink.

**Solution:** (As per the [theme documentation](https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/))

1. Login into Magento admin panel
2. Go to: `Stores > Configuration > Porto > Porto - Design Panel`
3. Open `Header` tab and check if there is Pink color selected for any background options.
4. If found then updated it to desired color and then clear the cache, you will see the updated background color on frontend.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your website https://midwestmegasquirt.com/
and I have applied some CSS there it's working perfectly from my side.
I have shared with you my CSS which I have applied.

```
.page-wrapper .page-header.type2.header-newskin .header.content {
    background: #a90000; //here you can put your color code as you want.
}
```

- You can put or replace my code on the below path.
  **app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/source/screen.css**
- After made changes you need to run these commands.
  **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

  php bin/magento cache:flush**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Krupa Popat - I would unset your background or overwrite it.

I would also check your codebase as i'd be inclined to believe that someone has been testing and physically written the word **pink** or it would render a hex value